# How to use GDI+ to fill a PNG image and keep its transparent layer?

Tags: c++, gdi+

When we want to fill a transparent icon image in Photoshop, it is very simple. Just press Ctrl + left mouse button, then select the non-transparent area of the icon, and then fill it with color.

I would like to ask everyone, how to use GDI+ to achieve this process, can you give a code example, please?

[image]

Comment: I would be very surprised if this is even possible. Photoshop is a tool to edit images; GDI+ is not.

Comment: take a look at the flood-fill and corresponding algorithms

Comment: GDI+ will only help you to save your modified bitmap as PNG (here is a example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-converting-a-bmp-image-to-a-png-image-use ) but to achieve your goal, you'll have to perform operations to RGBA data yourself, or using any image processing library...

Comment: You don't mention what C++ or environment you are working with; is it MFC, .NET, ATL, COM etc? You'll need to know, in your environment, how to: load a PNG with transparency into memory; how to draw colors onto a transparent image properly, and how to do a "paint bucket"-style fill. You might be able to use a color replace instead if you only need to replace solid colors. As it stands, this question is probably too vague and too broad to be a good fit for getting answers on StackOverflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.